# Play TOP songs of artist in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm trying to make an `AppleScript` which can play top songs of some artist. I've seen an iTunes script library via `ScriptEditor` but did't find anything useful for me. Hope someone can forward me in the right direction, if this case is possible to do. Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "top songs"? The songs with the highest play count?

Comment: @oa- There is special paragraph "Top songs" in iTunes

Answer (score 1):

The basic way of getting tracks from iTunes is using `get every track`. For example:

```
tell application "iTunes" to set topTracks to every track of playlist "Library" whose artist is "Golden Earring" and rating is 100
```

Ratings are 1 to 5 stars (or no stars) in the iTunes GUI, but are 0 to 100 in the backend. Multiply the rating by 20 for the backend rating (or divide the backend rating by 20 for the GUI star count), with zero stars equalling 0.

There is a quirk in iTunes; adding `and rating is 100` makes the query much slower, as if it’s doing a search on both queries and putting them together, rather than doing the easy one (artist) and then the hard one (rating). Because of that, this will probably be much, much faster at getting all of the five-rated tracks of a particular artist:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set artistTracks to every track of playlist "Library" whose artist is "Golden Earring"
    set topTracks to {}
    repeat with possibleTrack in artistTracks
        if the rating of possibleTrack is 100 then copy possibleTrack to end of topTracks
    end repeat
end tell
```

Now, if by “top songs", you mean the top *x* songs, then there is no guarantee that there will be enough rating five tracks to reach *x*. So if you want a specific *number* of tracks, you would have to grab the rating 5 tracks, see if you have enough, and if not, grab the rating 4 tracks, and so on. Here is one example of how to do that; there are many more. How, exactly, you do it will depend partly on how you define “top songs”.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set desiredArtist to "chi coltrane"

    --get topCount tracks
    set topCount to 5
    set fiveStars to {}
    set fourStars to {}
    set threeStars to {}
    set twoStars to {}
    set oneStar to {}
    set noStars to {}
    set allTracks to every track of playlist "Library" whose artist is desiredArtist

    --collect tracks into bins according to star rating
    --this is much faster than doing five searches with "and rating is"
    repeat with possibleTrack in allTracks
        copy (rating of possibleTrack) / 20 as integer to starRating

        if starRating is 5 then
            copy possibleTrack to end of fiveStars
        else if starRating is 4 then
            copy possibleTrack to end of fourStars
        else if starRating is 3 then
            copy possibleTrack to end of threeStars
        else if starRating is 2 then
            copy possibleTrack to end of twoStars
        else if starRating is 1 then
            copy possibleTrack to end of oneStars
        else
            copy possibleTrack to end of noStars
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

--collect the top tracks
set topTracks to {}
getTracks(fiveStars)
getTracks(fourStars)
getTracks(threeStars)
getTracks(twoStars)
getTracks(oneStar)
getTracks(noStars)

--play the tracks, if any
if (count of topTracks) > 0 then
    tell application "iTunes"
        repeat with topTrack in topTracks
            set topTrackID to the persistent ID of topTrack
            play topTrack
            --wait until this song is no longer playing, then go to the next
            repeat while the persistent ID of current track is topTrackID
                --delay a tenth of a second to avoid too much of the next random track
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end if

--add more tracks from the given trackList, until topCount is reached
--within a list, the choice of which tracks to use to reach topCount is somewhat arbitrary
on getTracks(trackList)
    global topTracks, topCount
    if (count of topTracks) ≥ topCount then return
    repeat with possibleTrack in trackList
        if (count of topTracks) ≥ topCount then
            return
        end if
        copy possibleTrack to end of topTracks
    end repeat
end getTracks
```

Other options for choosing when to advance to the next track in the *topTracks* list might include delaying for `the duration of topTrack as number`, if you are reasonably certain that no one will pause or advance the tracks in the GUI; it is also possible to set a handler that receives notification when a track changes.

Comment: Very thanks for this big answer. But can I get tracks not from my library, just from Apple Music lists?

Comment: I suspect not; however, your first step will have to be more clearly defining what you mean by “top songs of some artist”. That is, what are the criteria that must be met for a song to be “played”? It may help for you to provide an example, and the steps you took to reach this example. Once you do that, a solution using iTunes or using some other mechanism may become apparent.

Comment: iTunes has a special paragraph "Top songs" and I want to get this list. But it's also good if can get just a list of random songs of some artist.

Comment: What you’ll need to do is be much more precise about what you want to do, and how it relates to what you see. Often, for beginning programmers, it will help to describe specifically what another person would have to do to duplicate what you want. What steps do they need to take to find the “Top Songs”; what steps do they need to take to find “some artist”, and what steps do they need to take to “play” that song; then, what is the result? In this case, what do they hear? Once you know the steps, you can start thinking about ways to transform those steps into something a computer can do.